# Deploying a backend server with a large exe file

Tags: deployment

I want to deploy a server that receives some form data from the front end and writes it to a text file. Then a large exe file (~50mb) modifies that text file (file.exe in.txt out.txt) The modified text file is sent back to the front end. I have got it to work locally but whenever I try to deploy it takes too long or is too slow. So how do accomplish it?

I tried deploying on the free tier of render but deployment fails after a while.